# Slick Definition of the Category of Cartesian Closed Categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, universal-algebra

I can produce elementary definitions by just inspecting the definition on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+functor), but is there a readily available abstract definition? I vaguely remember seeing that they could be defined as algebras over some monad or something to do with enriched categories but I can't find anything.

Specifically, I would like something more "formal" than just "categories equipped with necessary adjunctions and functors that preserve them on the nose".

Even better would be if this definition could be very easily related to definitions of related categories like the category of cartesian categories or monoidal categories.

Comment: Cartesian and monoidal are actually easier than closed, since all the variances are the same. For instance a (strict) monoidal category is just a (strict) algebra for the free strict monoidal category 2-monad on the 2-category of categories. A lot of related stuff can be found in Lack's 2-categories companion, while Kelly's original doctrinal adjunction paper does some stuff about the closed situation.

Comment: You could probably say something like being "has simply typed lambda calculus as internal language" (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lambda-calculus).